# Look Up Modernizr Settings

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

Is there a way to look up Modernizr settings based on code ID that's made when you generate a custom download?

For example, I have file named *modernizr.custom.90563.js*. Is there a way to look up what settings where used bases on **90563**?

I need to add new settings to the file and I'd like to make sure I have all the options selected by the previous developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! If you view the source of your custom build, you'll see on the second line a link to the custom configuration, i.e.:

```
/* Modernizr 2.7.1 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
 * Build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-borderradius-boxshadow-opacity-cssanimations-csstransforms-csstransitions-geolocation-inlinesvg-svg-touch
 */
```

Copy/paste that link in your browser, and there's your custom config.

Comment: Thank you! It was almost too simple!